How to disable PackageParser log
In my apps I need to retrieve information about all installed apps on device. I use functions like packageManager.getInstalledApplications(flag) and packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).
These functions produce lots of warning logs from a class called PackageParser. Some of logs:
Unknown element under <application>: uses-native-library at /data/app/com.google.android.gm-gy0kYd_PiDg9M1EYiTno8g==/base.apk Binary XML file line #2336
Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data at /system/product/priv-app/GoogleDialer/GoogleDialer.apk Binary XML file line #81
No actions in intent filter at /system/product/app/Photos/Photos.apk Binary XML file line #930
Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in package: com.google.android.gm at: Binary XML file line #331

The logs are too much and annoying. Is there any way I can suppress them?

Try to add or modify the  element within the  tag to set the logcat configuration in AndroidManifest file. 

@DroidFlutter My app is'n developed with Dart. Is this still works? I have to put this in my application's manifest?

I apologize, I gave the code for the Dart. Check the AndroidManifest.xml file that each element is spelled correctly with the correct parent element.
